# Can we black-list the Android-tag?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

I have seen that some questions are tagged with `[android]`, but since this site is only about Android I don't see this tag usefull. Basically all questions should be tagged with that tag.

Can we black-list the `[android]` tag?

Comment: What about "android-market" - should we just use "market", since the inclusion of "android" is a tautology on this site?

Comment: See also: **Starting to deal with duplicate tags** http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/37/starting-to-deal-with-duplicate-tags

Comment: We're going to see a lot more "android" tags (and dupe questions that have post-dates PRIOR to the start of beta!), now that the gadgets.SE questions have been slurped in.

Comment: I agree, it should be black-listed.

Comment: I will delete the android tag from posts as I see it

Comment: It looks like this has reverted. We've been seeing the android tag on questions again, and not just migrated ones.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sounds like a good idea to me.

Answer (score 3):

Jeff Atwood nuked the Android tag.  I re-tagged questions that were left as untagged.

I'm not sure if this means users still be able to add new questions with the tag or not.

Comment: Whatever Jeff did, it doesn't prevent re-creation. A question was posted today with the [android] tag. I'll kill it, but it would be nice to have a more permanent solution.

Comment: @Al seems to be a particular problem with posts migrated across from SO/SU I noticed a couple come over with the Android tag earlier in the week and sorted them out.

Comment: @GAThrawn: You need to put at least 3 letters in your @[username] or [username] is never called.

Comment: @John well if he didn't see it back in January, he's probably not too bothered by now. Thanks, and this is why two letter first names should be outlawed ;)